# Function call returning fatal error: Call to undefined function getRecentProducts()

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom-block

Hi I am a newbie to magento. I'm trying to call a custom module block using `getChildHtml()` function which unfortunately is showing a fatal error: Call to undefined function `getRecentProducts()`

I am using magento 1.9.2.4

I have set up a child theme (childtheme) under magento default rwd theme.

I have copied page.xml from the default theme of rwd package.

I have also created a new layout file (home.phtml) and I am trying to get the block in this file.

I created a new block in active themes page.xml under `<default>` tag:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference"/>
```

Then in active themes local.xml:

```
<default>
    <reference name="newreference">
        <block type="recentproducts/recentproducts" name="recentproducts_recentproducts" template="recentproducts/recentproducts.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

And in my home.phtml file calling: `getChildHtml('newreference');`

The config file of module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Test_Recentproducts>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Test_Recentproducts>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <recentproducts>
        <class>Test_Recentproducts_Block</class>
      </recentproducts>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <recentproducts>
        <class>Test_Recentproducts_Model</class>
      </recentproducts>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

recentproducts.phtml

```
<?php
$products = $this­->getRecentProducts();
?>

<div id="product_list">
  <h1>Recent Products</h1>
  <?php if (is_array($products) && count($products)) { ?>
    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $product['url'] ?>"><?php echo $product['name'] ?></a>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Recentproducts.php (block)

```
class Test_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
  public function getRecentProducts() {
    // call model to fetch data
    $arr_products = array();
    $products = Mage::getModel("recentproducts/recentproducts")->getRecentProducts();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
      $arr_products[] = array(
        'id' => $product->getId(),
        'name' => $product->getName(),
        'url' => $product->getProductUrl()
      );
    }

    return $arr_products;
  }
}
```

Recentproducts.php (model)

```
class Test_Recentproducts_Model_Recentproducts extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
  public function getRecentProducts() {
    $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
                ->setPageSize(5);

    return $products;
  }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Update:

I tried to `get_class($this)` and it is perfectly returning the right class which is `Test_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts`.

Its also returning `getRecentProducts()` as a class method.

Comment: Where is the error occuring? Template file? Block class?

Comment: While calling the block function in template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I tested your code on a local installation, I assume you copied it from somewhere. The problem there is that `-` is not really a minus but some different special character (I haven't investigated further, sorry), and I was getting the same error you get. I wrote `$this->` myself and it did work.

Probably `$this­>getRecentProducts();` should be `$this­->getRecentProducts();`

Comment: Sorry that's a typo here. I'll edit it

Comment: Well, it was an answer somehow, it wasn't a critique. The problem is just a typo, nothing more. I updated my answer

Comment: You are a star. I lost my whole day debugging . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you created a file in recentproducts/block/recentproducts.php and this recentproducts.php file contains getRecentProducts() function.

Comment: Yes the files and functions are all present.

Comment: paste the RecentProducts.php code on your question

Comment: pasted above...

Comment: is compilation mode is enabled??

Comment: No its disabled

Comment: go to includes folder. and edit config.php. comment all line on there

Comment: Commented the lines. Still no luck

Comment: Use `$block = new Test_Recentproducts_Block_Recentproducts(); $products = $block->getRecentProducts();`  On .phtml page

Comment: Well this should obviously work but what is the actual problem if we go by magento way.